# If datetimepicker value greater than end datetimepicker value then

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write an if statement for two datetimepickers.  I have a start date and end date and I do not want the value of the start date to be greater than the end date.

Here is what I have tried but doesn't work:

```
If dateStart.Value.Date < dateend.Value.Date Then

    lblstatus.Text = "Status: Start date must be a date before end date."

Else

End If
```

Comment: You are showing the error message if the start date is **less** than the end date. It looks like you need to use `>=` instead of `<` in the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Operator is wrong .. it should be greater than, not less than :)

```
    If dateStart.Value.Date > dateend.Value.Date Then

        lblstatus.Text = "Status: Start date must be a date before end date."

    Else
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lblstatus.Text = dateStart.Value.Date > dateEnd.Value.Date ? "Status: Start date must be a date before end date." : dateStart.Value.Date(Or whatever you want to happen if it is a valid date by your condition check)
```

Answer (score 0):

as alternative you can change the `.MinDate` and  `.MaxDate` properties in the `ValueChanged` event

```
Sub init()
    AddHandler dateStart.ValueChanged, Sub() dateEnd.MinValue = dateStart.Value
    AddHandler dateEnd.ValueChanged, Sub() dateStart.MaxValue = dateEnd.Value
End Sub
```